# Best practice for Uploading files using MultiFormDataContent in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an upload `api` that receives a list of `IFiles` to upload to a server.  I now require an additional string to describe the upload for information details.  My current controller looks like:

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
{
   // upload to server and other stuff
}
```

To access the string, I have changed the controller:

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files, string uploadDescription)
{
   //some code
}
```

I now have access to the `uploadDescription`. When testing this I am sending the files as `MultipartFormDataContent`, and the description as a query parameter.
Although this works, I am not sure sending query parameters in this way with a `post` action is best practice or not. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no best practice for doing such a `Post` method, but from my knowledge this is better and readable to pass a unit DTO to your method either `Post` or `Get`, so I think it would be better to change it like :

```
public class FileSpec
{
    public List<IFormFile> Files {get; set;}
    public string UploadDescription {get; set;}
}
```

and change your method signature like :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]FileSpec fileSpec)
```

anyway this is depend on yourself you pass parameters separately or pass them as a DTO.

you can also read more about parameter binding [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

Comment: thanks, I am new to this and so far my understanding is that to bind to IForm, the content will have to passed as a multipartformdatacontent.  How would I specify content type a DTO?

Comment: finally have worked this out using custom model binding to send a MultiPartFormdataContent request that includes both json and filestream.  This article very helpful and explains the approach. https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2018/09/04/handling-multipart-requests-with-json-and-file-uploads-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Sorry I was off for several days, good you finally found the clue.